# Jenkins Pipeline using Openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline on Openshift, that automatically runs a Jenkins service when we start the pipeline build. I referred few templates online and created a Jenkins pod and a pipeline. But whenever I try to run the pipeline, It shows build status as "not started. 
Later, I created a standalone Jenkins service in Openshift, created a Jenkins file in open shift and tried executing it. I encountered authentication issues while connecting with Openshift from Jenkins.

Can anyone guide me, if I am missing something or any other working templates for a pipeline?

Thanks

Comment: if you wish to get a specific answer, please expose specific details.

Answer (score 1):

It’s because of permissions 
Jenkins runs with Jenkins user and openshift doesn’t know how to connect to it

Create a new service account in openshift jenkins